# Websocket Private Chat Application

Tags: php, security, websocket, chat

I am new to the websocket concept and that's why I am writing this topic. I would like to know how I can secure a chat room so that only two specific users can only subscribe to it. To be clearer let me give you an example.

/chats/room/{firstUserId}-{secondUserId}

which for user ids 114 & 43 will be

/chats/room/114-43

and only those users will be able to join that room. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client opens a websocket by issuing an HTTP GET on a URL. It's exactly the same as a normal HTTP GET with a few header fields set, like:

```
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
```

The server subsequently `hijacks` that connection. In other words, nothing prevents you from using exactly the scheme you want, i.e. `/chats/room/114-43`, if you like it. Websocket URL is just an URL.